# How can I divide my book into different project without repeating myself?

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I am trying to create a mini book with LaTeX on Windows in order to learn the basic thing with LaTeX.

I would like to divide my book into different projects but I have some sort of style defined for whole document. When I divide it into different section, I need to apply this design over and over again.

How can I achieve that without repeating myself? Is there something like Master Page on LaTeX?

Comment: The `\input` command is your friend. :)

Comment: @CountZero if you can provide any sample code, you will be my friend ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose you have a main file, in which you have the style definitions. At some point then you can insert the other chapters like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{<somepackage>}

\begin{document}

Your text

\input{chapter1}

More text

\input{chapter2}

etc.

\end{document}
```

The `\input` command will take as an argument the name of the `LaTeX` file you want to insert. The extension is required only if it is different from `.tex`. There is the 'brother' of this command, `\include`. The difference is explained here: [When should I use \input vs \include ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/7417)

Answer (score 2):

Besides keeping you style definitions and list of packages in a separate file and including them with `\usepackage{<somepackage>}`, I'd recommend you use [the `standalone` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone) as well. This will allow you to compile each chapter as you go and and then use that file directly in the main book.

So, first create a `somepackage.sty` file to contain all your custom macros and packages such as:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}% or any others that you use
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text
\usepackage{standalone}% Need standalone package
```

This file will become sort of you master page. I'd include the [geometry](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry) information for the margins in here, watermarks, as well as any footers, headers, etc...

Then create separate files for each chapter.  Here is an example for `chapter1.tex` which is a complete file and can be compiled by itself:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{somepackage}% your custom list of macros and packages
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
    \section{}
    \lipsum[1]% ... contents of chapter 1 here...
\end{document}
```

Similarly for the other chapters. Then your main file would look like:

```
\documentclass{book}  
\usepackage{somepackage}% your custom list of macros and packages

\begin{document}
  \input{chapter1}
  \input{chapter2}
\end{document}
```

One important thing to keep in mind is that main file must include the `standalone` package as well as all ALL the packages required by the individual chapter files.

Answer (score 1):

It is opssible too to include the definitions. Assuming you have a file called `layout.tex` contaning all your packages (and maybe the class too) and definitions you can use it with

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{layout}
\begin{document}
  Text
\end{document}
```

If you like to use `layout.tex` in many documents you can move it to your user `texmf` folder to make LaTeX find it like a package or class file. To find out the right file open the “Run-Program“ (Don’t know the english name it’s “Eingabeaufforderung“ in German windows) and type `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [subfiles](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfiles) package, which would allow you to have the entire preamble in the master document, and then each separate file will inherit the preamble of the main file when compiled. It functions similarly to the `standalone` package mentioned above.

Comment: subfiles does not allow to use command like 'includeonly`, but it does however allow you nest files.