# Creating a common settings file

Tags: input, workflow

I have created a file which provides convenient options to change the settings for all of my documents. For e.g.:

```
\def\BookFontRoman{Gentium Plus}
\def\BookFontCJK{Adobe Song Std}
\def\PageWidth{280}
\def\PageHeight{209}
\def\DisplayFootnotes{1} %1=yes, 0=no
\def\LongTitlePage{1} %1=yes, 0=no
```

Saved as `settings.tex`, this can be read through the use of `\input{settings}`. My documents also contain `etoolbox` if-then conditionals to check some values. However, I also use some `BASH` scripts to assist in the generation of some LaTeX code.

This has some benefits:

- I can establish consistent settings for all of my documents.
- I need not edit to critical source code to make these formatting adjustments.

Can you recommend a better way to store settings?

- Is there a more simpler format for putting such information into a single file?
- Is there a solution for allowing `BASH` scripts to also access this information or (if that is too difficult) access other information also stored later in the file (which is ignored by `XeTeX`)?

Comment: You should keep the bash scripts separate unless you're doing something very unusual. Can you elaborate on what it is your scripts are doing? There is probably a LaTeX equivalent. Otherwise, you can bundle all the TeX stuff into your own `.sty` file and include it in your document with `\usepackage`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using a `.tex` file I would use a package or wrapper class like shown in the answers to ["Many documents, same preamble"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33917/many-documents-same-preamble).

`bash` syntax is very different from LaTeX syntax so I would not try to parse the LaTeX settings with a `bash` script. But you may add a command to your package or wrapper class to write a `.sh` file with all the settings. `bash` could then write a minimal document and run LaTeX to this, to generate the `.sh` file, e.g.

```
% example package
\ProvidesPackage{mysetting}[2011/11/23]
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}% because you're using new booleans with etoolbox
\newcommand*{\examplesetting}{Okay}
\newcommand*{\anothersetting}{OK}
% …
\newwrite\bashsettings
\newcommand*{\writesettingsto}[1]{%
  \immediate\openout\bashsettings #1
  \immediate\write\bashsettings{%
    examplesetting='\examplesetting'^^J%
    anothersetting='\anothersetting'
  }%
  \closeout\bashsettings
}
```

The bash script may do

```
echo '\documentclass{minimal}\usepackage{mysetting}\writesettingto{mysettings.sh}\begin{document}\end{document}' > createsettings.tex
latex -interaction=batchmode createsettings.tex || exit -1
. mysettings.sh
```

You may extend this with a configuration file, e.g. `mysettings.cfg` that will be loaded at the end of your package, e.g.

```
\ProvidesFile{mysetting.cfg}[2011/11/23]
\renewcommand*{\anothersetting}{Not OK}
\endinput
```

And add line

```
\InputIfFileExists{mysetting.cfg}{}{}
```

At the end of `mysetting.sty`. So you don't need to edit the package (or wrapper class) to change settings of a project, but only put a `mysettings.cfg` into the project folder.