# How do I load a custom class in LyX?

Tags: lyx, documentclass-writing, document-configuration

I'm interested in making some modifications to a standard class to use as the class for many documents I'm creating, and see that one way to do this is to simply create a "[wrapper class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33947/7844)". This approach makes a lot of sense for my application and will (I think) be easy to maintain. But I can't see how to get my documents to use this class. I understand how to do this using LaTeX directly, but not using LyX.

What do I need to do to get my class to appear in the list of classes listed in `Document > Settings... > Document Class`?

Comment: I've figured it out and posted a [proposed answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43729/7844).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the wrapper class has been made available to LyX, all you have to do is create a corresponding "layout" file, `myclass.layout`, containing

```
#\DeclareLaTeXClass[myclass]{My Custom Class}
Input base-class.layout
```

and then choose the class for your document with

```
Document > Settings... > Document Class > Local Layout...
```

and browse to and select `myclass.layout`.

If you want to make the layout generally available, then it needs to be added to the LyX layouts folder on your system (e.g., ~/.lyx/layouts/ on UNIX), which will cause it to appear among the listed layouts in the Document Class dialog as "My Custom Class".