# How to reuse new command among different files to keep them consistent?

Tags: macros, best-practices

I have several `.tex` files with `\newcommand` in the beginning, I found it really cumbersome to *copy and paste* these new commands each time I have a new `.tex` file, and it is easy to make mistakes and hard to keep the new commands up to date. Is there a way to make a head file with all my new commands, typeset it so that the new commands apply to all my tex files?

Comment: Create your own `\mycommands.sty` style file, so that each invocation of it is merely `\usepackage{mycommands}`.  It starts with `\ProvidesPackage{mycommands}` and ends with `\endinput`.  What goes in between is up to you.

Comment: write all the defines in a separate file and use `\include` or `\import` http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use \input vs. \include?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include)

Comment: Note that Steven meant to write `mycommands.sty` not `\mycommands.sty`.

Comment: @jon: In such cases we would give a kingdom for editing comments even after 5 minutes ;-)

Comment: does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33917/many-documents-same-preamble help?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- Yes, indeed! (This site is riddled with non-sequiturs of my own devising....)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: In such cases I sometimes delety my comment and write a new one .

Comment: @UlrichDiez: Inefficient ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Sure. Having to choose between efficiency and accurateness in situations where I cannot have both sometimes seems like a big ethical dilemma to me. That's one of the aspects that I like about TeX-LaTeX Stack Exchange: I always find obliging assistance and advice when being confronted with such things. :-)

Comment: @TimothyTruckle never use `\include ` for including definitions, it should only be used after `\begin{document}`

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way would be to just place your common macro definitions into a separate `.tex` file an `\input` <sup>1</sup> this  in the preamble of all documents.

You can also just make your own package. The only differences (if you don't want to use package options with it) are to name it `somename.sty` and to add `\ProvidesPackage{somename}` as first macro. Then load it using `\usepackage{somename}` instead of `\input.`

Note that you can place you common file into your own TEXMF tree where it is then found by LaTeX, so that the file does not need to be in the same directory any more.

<sup>1)</sup> no, do not use `\include` for this

Comment: Why should we not use \include ?