# "import" all my packages and custom commands into a new file automatically

Tags: macros, packages

I am new to latex, so apologies if this is a trivial question. I have amassed many useful packages and custom commands and start each document by copy/pasting all of them above "\begin{document}". Is there a way to automate this? Can I have one command which will collect all the packages and commands I like to use?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome ! Basically, you could very well write a `settings.tex` file will all of your favorite packages and do `\input{settings.tex}` just after `\documentclass[xxx]{xxx}`. It's what I do all the time ! Have a look at related questions here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33917/many-documents-same-preamble

Comment: Thank you! This answers my question,but I can't accept it as a good answer ):.

Comment: I believe this is some sort of duplicate of multiple previous questions so I won't post an answer, but feel free to ask other questions whenever you need.