# Can I amend the preamble from outside the preamble?

Tags: input, preamble

I am writing a document (`mydoc.tex`) that will include a section as a separate document (`mysection.tex`) using `\input{mysection.tex}`.

If I want to include something in the preamble (specifically `\DeclareMathOperator{}{}`), must this be done in the preamble of `mydoc.tex` or can I include it in `mysection.tex`?

Comment: Perhaps [how can i divide my book into different project without repeating myself](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32041/how-can-i-divide-my-book-into-different-project-without-repeating-myself) might be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\DeclareMathOperator` *must* go before `\begin{document}`, so there's no choice.

However, the concept of `\input` is quite easy:

```
\input{mysection}
```

will make TeX behave as if the entire contents of `mysection.tex` were at that point. It's best to put all personal commands in the document's preamble, so that you know precisely where to find them.